# Logstash error: open /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml: permission denied

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logging, backend, kibana

I have a logging repo that contains kibana, logstash, elasticsearch and a setup file, it is running on a server and works well, but now i want to run it on another server using docker but didn't run and it returns that the permission denied.

I have ran docker compose logs -f for setup it return the following: **Could not resolve host. Is Elasticsearch running?**
Note: it build correctly and show started but just filebeat and setup are up, logstash and elasticsearch are  not.

Comment: Without seeing the compose setup, error analysis is not possible. --- I have a [sample setup in `bitbucket`](https://bitbucket.org/turing85/uber-docker-compose/src/cce1d746fcdf33fb38d3f9fbf71eb0a4eed59a9c/localdeployment/docker-compose.yml#lines-189), feel free to copy what you need.

Comment: @Turing85 the problem is not with the setup because it works correctly with different servers and on localhost, the problem is on the new server, so it is server side problem

Comment: The this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. It might be better suited for [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).